# How to print to Terminal in two different places with Python?

Tags: python, datetime, python-multithreading, blessed

I'm creating a small little terminal program. I would like to display the changing time, among other things. To display the time, I use the datetime module, along with the blessed module. My code looks like this:

```
import blessed
from datetime import datetime

def displayTime():
    location = term.get_location()
    while True:
        currentTime = datetime.now()
        a = datetime(currentTime.year, currentTime.month, currentTime.day, currentTime.hour, currentTime.minute, currentTime.second)
        with term.location():
            print(term.move_xy(location[1], location[0]) + str(a))
        time.sleep(1)
```

This works perfectly fine. Now, I need to print other things to the output window. Or execute a function.

I tried this by using threading.

```
import threading

time = threading.Thread(target = displayTime())
time.start()
print("test")
```

However, this failed to do it's job. This should have resulted with output that printed this:

2023-08-23 hour:minute:second
test

But I did not get the expected result. If you have an answer, I would also like to know if user input is possible as well. Thank you.

Comment: `displayTime()` immediately calls and executes the function, which results in an endless loop, and thus won’t even progress to starting the thread. You want to pass the function without calling it there.